# Meaning of "within a period of not more than one month preceding the date of expiry"?

Tags: phrases, idioms, time, legalese

I have to renew a license and the rule states that "**the application has to be submitted within a period of not more than one month preceding the date of expiry**".

So the date of expiry is ***OCTOBER 11th***. So does it mean that I can renew **anytime** **between** *September 11th and October 11th*? Or does it mean that the last date for the application **is** *September 11th*?

I'm confused because of the wordings used in the rules. I understand that similar questions have been asked before but not exactly for the wordings used in the above context.

Thank you in advance for any help offered. Much appreciated.

Comment: What does "within" mean?

Comment: "Within ... not more than" is a bit confusing.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question about whether the word *within* can mean its opposite, outside.

Comment: ***not more than one month preceding the date of expiry*** means you can't apply ***two*** (or three, or more) months before the expiry. You have to wait until the expiry is only ***one month or less*** in the future. Presumably you can apply, say, six months ***after*** expiry (the relevant number being ***minus six***, which is obviously less than  one), provided you can explain why you didn't need a licence during the intervening period.

Answer (score 2):

'A period' is a certain length of time - here dictated as 'one month'.

'Not more than one month' means pretty well 'one month or less'.

'Preceding' is coming before, and October is preceded by September.

So, any time between 11th Sept. and 11th Oct is the window given for application submission - i.e.one calendar month.

Comment: I disagree. According to your final paragraph, a renewal application submitted on ***12th Oct*** wouldn't be valid, because it's outside the specified date range. I can understand that if you wanted to "renew" a licence several decades after it expired, you might not be able to use the "renewal" procedure in quite the same way. But I doubt *any* licensing authority would have a problem with renewing a short time after expiry.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - in the real world you'd probably find that was the case. But that wasn't what the question was about.

Comment: @Tim Thank you for the clarification. In my head that was the thinking process too. So from what you are saying, in this specific context, the application window for the renewal is between 11th Sept and 11th Oct. Got it. Cheers mate!